# c++ map containing a list

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdlist

I would like to create a map where the key is an int, and the value is a list of arrays (`int[][]`).

I tried this :

```
const int R = 4, C = 5;
std::map<int, std::list<int[R][C]> > s;
```

but it won't compile and I don't understand why ... (R and C are parameter of the program but do not change during execution).

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't really a good description of the problem you are seeing. You should really tell us what goes wrong if you want anybody to be able to help...

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to use vector<int> instead? R and C must not be parameters of program, whatever is changed or not. They has to be constant and has to be of known value. Because size of int[R][C] has to be known at the time of compilation. You have to use dynamically resized arrays as vector is in C++, if that number are not known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are not copy constructable or copy assignable, which an element of a standard container must be. Your code will compile as is, but the array type breaks the requirements for the standard containers and you'll run into undefined behaviour. You can't have an `std::list<int[R][C]>`. However, C++11 provides a nice new compile-time constant sized `std::array` for your pleasure:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<int, C>, R> array_2d;
typedef std::list<array_2d> array_list;
std::map<int, array_list> s;
```

Otherwise, other alternatives are to use `std::vector` instead of `std::array` (preferred), or to have a `std::list` of `int**` and dynamically allocate your 2D arrays.

However, I'd consider a bit of a rethink of your design. Is this really the structure you want? Should any of the data be grouped into a `struct`?

Comment: However, the OP's code compiles fine under GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2

Comment: okay, thank you, but I do not have c++11 ... have you another solution?

Comment: @Jav: What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
For compatibility reasons, I cannot change something on this side.

Comment: @AndyProwl I believe he's hitting undefined behaviour by breaching the requirements of the standard containers.

Comment: You can change array with vector and get nearly the same behavior with only minimal more work.